# What does the exclamation mark mean before a function call?

Tags: dart

I was following a PR for Flutter and came across this code:

```
if (chunkCallback != null) {
  chunkCallback!(0, 100);
}
```

What does the exclamation mark mean after `chunkCallback`? Nothing I search on Google works.

Comment: Can also be written as `chunkCallback?.call(0, 100);`

Comment: Whoever downvoted, if you could explain, that would be more helpful as I could improve my question. Thanks!

Comment: Yes @lrn, that was actually suggested in the PR, but my question was specifically about the "!". Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Doesn't the if-statement already change the type of chunkCallback to be non-nullable inside the curlies?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`"!"` is a new dart operator for conversion from a *nullable* to a *non-nullable* type.
Read [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety) and [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) about sound null safety.

Use it only if you are absolutely sure that the value will never be **null** and do not confuse it with the [conditional property access](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#conditional-property-access) operator.

Comment: if the method was null and I call it using "!" operator, the app might crash. is there a way to call this method safely ?

Comment: @JAHelia yes, check if the variable possibly containing the method does not equal null

Comment: As mentioned in @user13315601's answer, the term you'd google for is "null-assertion-operator"

Comment: @JAHelia You probably know this already, but for the sake of completeness, you can safely call a nullable function via `chunkCallback?.call(0, 100);`. This is way shorter than checking for null.

Answer (score 18):

`chunkCallback` is a nullable reference to a function.

If you are sure that `chunkCallback` can't be null at runtime you can "Cast away nullability" by adding `!` to it to make compiler happy

```
typedef WebOnlyImageCodecChunkCallback = void Function(
    int cumulativeBytesLoaded, int expectedTotalBytes);

...

class Class1 {
  final WebOnlyImageCodecChunkCallback? chunkCallback;

  Class1(this.chunkCallback);

  void test() {
    if (chunkCallback == null) {
      throw Exception("chunkCallback is null");
    }

    chunkCallback!.call(0, 100);
  }
}
```

Esentially, `!` in this case is a syntactic sugar for

```
(chunkCallback as WebOnlyImageCodecChunkCallback).call(0, 100);
```

Comment: Finally a sane, concise, and understandable description.

Answer (score 10):

I think it is a shorthand syntax for “Casting away nullability”, as per the docs: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#null-assertion-operator

Answer (score 2):

The variable `chunkCallback` must be able to accept null and you cannot call a function on a nullable type without either using `!` or `?`. This is part of Darts sound null safety

Some great videos on this:

[Flutter vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYhOU9AuaFs)

[YouTube vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgBwnMhz5nE&t=94s)

Even though the conditional statement checks for null, Dart still requires the exclamation mark before the function call. The difference between using `!` over `?` is that it will throw an exception instead of using the variable if the value is null.

Some examples:

```
class Car {
  String? make; // String or null type

  Car([this.make]); // parameter is optional
}

main() {
  Car test = Car('Ford'); // initialised with a value
  Car test2 = Car(); // no value given so null is default

  // returns 4
  if (test.make != null) {
    print(test.make!.length); // ! still needed even though !=null condition stated
  } else {
    print('The value is null');
  }

  // returns The value is null
  if (test2.make != null) {
    print(test2.make!.length);
  } else {
    print('The value is null');
  }
}
```

Above example shows that conditional check for null is not enough.

And choosing between ? and !

```
class Customer {
  String? name; 
  String? surname; 

  Customer(this.name, [this.surname]); // constructor with optional parameter []

}

main() {

 Customer ford = Customer('John'); //only name is given a value

 // calling a method on a nullable type doesn't work
 // so ? and ! used here after variable name and before method

 print(ford.name!.length); // operation executed as usual => 4

 print(ford.surname?.length); // ? on null value returns null => null

 print(ford.surname!.length);  // Exception is thrown => TypeError

}
```