# Flutter 2.0 The argument type 'Color?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'

Tags: flutter

After I updated the flutter sdk to >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, there's a weird error saying that `The argument type 'Color?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'` when I try to assign the border color to the card widget, what is going on here?

```
Card(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue[300], width: 2.0),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)
  ),
  child: Text('Demo')),
```

Full code to reproduce the error:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue[300], width: 2.0),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              ),
              child: Text('Demo')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter null safety - The argument type 'Color?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66706203/flutter-null-safety-the-argument-type-color-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parame)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

just do this

```
 color: (Colors.blue[300])!,
```

it is a feature in dart `Null safty`
for more information please check this link

https://medium.com/flutter/null-safety-flutter-tech-preview-cb5c98aba187

Comment: Color warning went away, now I am getting "Invalid constant value"

Comment: above link doesn't explain exclamation mark, so read it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63253350/614026

Comment: so confused about this feature, make Color so complicated, Now I cannot assign Color.lightBlueAccent[700] to a primary Color ...

Comment: The null safety thing in Flutter is the worst thing that has ever happened to this language. Let me handle null safety! It now takes ages to fix these stupid problems!!!

Answer (score 18):

You could alternatively do

```
color: Colors.blue.shade300
```

which gives the same result.

See the flutter docs for more info:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors-class.html

Comment: This works for me, thanks!

Comment: This is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe in the future using the bang operator [!]

```
color: Colors.blue[300]!;
```

will provoke some problems, if you ever get an error, it might appear the error of: `Null check operator used on a null value`
so to solve that, you should do:

```
var color = Colors.blue[300];
color: color as Color
```

try to avoid the bang operator unless you really know what you're doing, hope it helps to someone!