# Flutter null safety - The argument type 'Color?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

I changed my SDK version for flutter to min , so that I can fix my code for null safety.

There is one issue that I don't understand,
this line produces the following error:

```
The argument type 'Color?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'

border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[300], width: 1),
```

but if I change `Colors.grey[300]` with whatever value that doesn't use `[]`, it will work,
so `Colors.grey` works perfectly fine.

What should I change here to keep using `grey[300]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `0xFFE0E0E0` for grey[300].

To pick material colors you can use this [tool](https://material.io/resources/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0&primary.color=6002ee).

To select a specific color from one of the swatches, index into the swatch using an integer for the specific color desired, as follows:

```dart
Color selection = Colors.green[400]!; // Selects a mid-range green.
```

Each ColorSwatch constant is a color and can used directly. For example:

```
Container(
  color: Colors.blue, // same as Colors.blue[500] or Colors.blue.shade500
)
```

Comment: yeah I noticed that, but does this mean using specific shades of a color with [x] is not allowed anymore since null safety in flutter 2?

Comment: Well yeah, you can check issue here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71591#issue-755539014

Answer (score 20):

**Problem:**

```
Color color = Colors.grey[300]; // Error in null-safe mode
```

When you use `Colors.grey[300]`, you're actually getting the color from a `Map` which Dart (in null-safe mode) warns you about because that value could be `null`. [See more](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#the-map-index-operator-is-nullable)

---

**Solutions:**

There are two solutions for it. One is general and one is only specific to this case.

1. **Use Bang operator (`!`)**

   ```
   Color color = Colors.grey[300]!  // Added '!', error gone
   ```
2. **Use `shadeXXX` on the `Color`**

   ```
   Color color = Colors.grey.shade300;
   ```

Comment: Tried this, now I am getting "Invalid constant value"

Comment: @giorgio79 Although it is unrelated but what color are you using?

Comment: Yeah, tried to use one of the shades. Turns out those are not constant, so have to use hex code Color(#123456...) lol. One of the bigger piles of dung in Flutter

Comment: @giorgio79 But my answer doesn't have to do anything with it. You must already be getting the same error before using this answer. For example: `Colors.grey[300]` was already a non-const in the first place.

Comment: Some description on the first solution.  Use Bang operator `!` only if you're sure that the object will never evaluated to null

Answer (score 1):

use shade300 like
Color color = Colors.grey.shade300;

Comment: No, the above returns an invalid constant value error.

Answer (score 0):

You can write
Colors.grey[300]! like this and this will work.

Comment: No, the above returns an invalid constant value error.