# The non-nullable variable '_preferences' must be initialized. Try adding an initializer expression

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety, flutter-sharedpreference

I am trying to implement a class where i can call SharedPreferences funtions.

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';


class UserPreferences {
  static SharedPreferences _preferences;

  static const _keyToken = 'token';

  static Future init() async {
    _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  static Future setToken(String token) async =>
    await _preferences.setString(_keyToken, token);

  static String getToken() => _preferences.getString(_keyToken);

}
```

But i am getting following error:

```
The non-nullable variable '_preferences' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create an object when you create your variable like below inside the method:

```
  static Future init() async {
    SharedPreferences _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
```

And for using like the property you can do it like below:

```
static SharedPreferences _preferences = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

And when you call this property you can use `async/await` for this `_preferences` property on that page.

Comment: but the await is not gonna work without async and how i can a put async

Comment: `static SharedPreferences _preferences = SharedPreferences.getInstance() as SharedPreferences;`      this line worked. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Add `late` to the declaration of `_preferences`, like this:

```dart
static late SharedPreferences _preferences;
```

Final code:

```dart
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class UserPreferences {
  static late SharedPreferences _preferences;

  static const _keyToken = 'token';

  static Future init() async {
    _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  static Future setToken(String token) async =>
      await _preferences.setString(_keyToken, token);

  static String getToken() => _preferences.getString(_keyToken);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Understanding the Problem

> The non-nullable variable '_preferences' must be initialized.

With NULL safety in place, you no longer can leave Non-Nullable types uninitialized.

```
 static SharedPreferences _preferences;
```

Here you have not initialized the non-nullable `SharedPreferences`.

---

#### Solution

**1. Initialize it**

```
 static Future init() async {
    SharedPreferences _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance() as SharedPreferences;;
  }
```

**2. Make it Nullable**

> **NOTE** : This solution will work but is not recommended as you are making it nullable which means it can hold `null` (can cause crashes in future program flow).

Add `?` to make it "NULLABLE"

```
 static SharedPreferences? _preferences;
```

Comment: Initially I thought when I wrote this answer but then I found out that you used [my formatting signature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67623408/6618622), haha.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad hahaha.....But coincidentally even I came up with this format. I got to know today that you also follow this format :)

Comment: I've been using this format for almost a year and you haven't seen any of my answers written this way (being a Flutter developer) is kinda strange!

Comment: @CopsOnRoad yeah dude! Have you been a little inactive last month. Because most of my answers were posted last month and didn't see any of your answers

Comment: Well, I don't really check all the "newly posted questions" now, although I used to do that a couple of years ago. Regardless, I've been posting answers on SO for almost 3 years now and most of my answers (which I am sure almost everyone active in "Flutter") must have seen them (probably including you, haha). So, my format is actually ~2-3 years old. Here's one such old unedited [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57132247/6618622)

Comment: So you mean I copied yours ? Is that what you are trying to say ? If yes , I would like to say that our minds probably just worked the same to come up with this format. I never had a look at your answers before tbh

Comment: All I was saying is your this line "I never had a look at your answers before tbh" doesn't sound that true because as I mentioned earlier, almost my all answers have that format and the chances of you not seeing any of my posts is almost zero.