# Dart: Exclamation Mark before vs after identifier

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm wondering what the difference is between say

`someVariable!` vs `!someVariable`.

I'm aware of the whole non-nullible concept, and as far as I know this applies to `someVariable!`, but then what happens if the exclamation mark comes before the variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This answer may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63253015/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-mean-before-a-function-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!variable means `not variable` used in boolean expressions. Its python or english equivalent would be

```
if not variable: //From if (!variable)
```

Hope it helps. Let me know if you have any other queries